# Minecraft: How to make an arrow that when it lands it summons a lightning? 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How to make an arrow that when it lands it summons a lightning? I want it for a minigame please help its in 1.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have 2 command blocks 1 comparator 1 redstone torch 2 blocks(1 any block and 1 redstone block) set up like this.

redstone block
command block/comparator/any block/redstone torch/command block
put the 1st command block into repeat. 
torch should be hanging from the block so when the comparator activate the torch deactivates then 2nd command block charges.
1st command execute @e[type=arrow] ~~~ testforblock ~~-1~ air
2nd command execute @e[type=arrow] ~~~ summon lightning_bolt ~~~
If this doesn't work i think this is for bedrock edition only